# A Scheduled Task to transfer one LARGE file from one mapped drive to another failed but worked when file split into 3 separate files

Tags: scheduled-tasks, file-transfer, windows-task-scheduler, mapped-drive

I am trying to transfer a large AFP file from one mapped drive to another via a Scheduled Task

The Scheduled Task failed I guess because the file didn't transfer and no error logging on the task so I separated the file into 3 segments and ran the task again and it worked

PS This Scheduled Task runs on a daily basis and doesn't normally cause any problems with the transfer of files

I tried running the Scheduled Task again manually but again the large file would not transfer, but when I split the file into 3 smaller files and ran the Scheduled Task the 3 files transferred without problem ???